# Get Partner center SDK Reconciliation data

Tags: c#, api

Hello everyone and thank you for reading this. I am not sure where to post this issue so ill start here, feel free to direct me to the appropriate place to post this.

I have been looking into the Partner SDK sample ([Github](https://github.com/PartnerCenterSamples/Partner-Center-SDK-Samples) & [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/scenarios)) and I don't seem to find a specific scenario, I want to get the same data that the reconciliation file has on the CSP portal but in code (c#), the fields are the ones described [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/use-the-reconciliation-files#a-href-idusagebasedfilesausage-based-file-fields).

I have gone through the sample scenario's but couldn't find anything close to what I need. Can someone advise me where or what to look for? Thank you very much!

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reconciliation files contain with two parts: "Summary" and "Daily Usage". All of them can be obtained by "Get invoice line items":

- "Summary" - ../v1/invoices/{invoice-id}/lineitems/{provider}/BillingLineItems
- "Daily Usage" - ../v1/invoices/{invoice-id}/lineitems/{provider}/UsageLineItems

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-invoiceline-items

Comment: as this is correct, the method provided is through the REST API which i am not using, we are using the NuGet Package Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter. The methods i needed are indeed to be found under "Get invoice line items", thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So i have been trough the code more profoundly and have found what i was looking for (at least for now). I have created a combination of multiple functions and a custom export to csv (which fitted my needs).

Kind regards